# Initialization of object static members

Tags: c++, class, static, global-variables

Static members confuse me sometimes. I understand how to initialize a simple built in type such as `int` with something along the lines of `int myClass::statVar = 10;`, which you place in a .cpp file, but I have something of the following sort:

```
class myClass
{
public:
 // Some methods...

protected:
 static RandomGenerator itsGenerator;
}
```

The basic idea is simple enough: `myClass` needs access to a random generator for one of its member functions. I also can have only a few instances of the generator since each object is quite big. However, the `RandomGenerator` type needs to be "initialized", so to speak, by a call to `RandomGenerator::Randomize()`, which the compiler won't allow you to do since it's not a const rvalue (is that right?).

So how can I make this work?

Or perhaps should I not make use of a static variable in this case, and do it some other way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could create wrapper class which will hold `RandomGenerator` instance in it and will call `RandomGenerator::Randomize` in its constructor.

Comment: It is BAD. The outer class should not know about existence of the generator. You changed the way to it only. It is a workaround, but it is not a SOLUTION.

Comment: @Gangnus: Not necessarily. Encapsulation is all well and good, but there's nothing wrong with providing policies from the outside, especially if you're at risk of lumping more than a single responsibility into your existing outer class.

Answer (score 2):

Put it in a private field, expose a static accessor. In the accessor, if the member is not yet initialized, initialize it.

Comment: I'm banking towards this method. I think it may be the better solution, though wrapping the generator also seems like an elegant idea.

Comment: It is BAD. The outer class should not know about existence of the generator. You changed the way to it only. It is a workaround, but it is not a SOLUTION.

Answer (score 1):

In cases such as these, singletons actually are your friends, despite their other drawbacks.

Comment: Yes. I am afraid, in c++ it is the only really correct way. Any setting of a deeply inner private field from the outer space is BADLY incorrect. Outers space should not know about inner generator and its initialization.

Comment: @Gangus: See my other comments. That's not necessarily true. Sometimes it's fine to provide a policy from the outside. See the standard library — you can provide allocation types as template parameters to basically all the container types, and that is completely fine.

Answer (score 1):

If `RandomGenerator` is copyable, you can use a helper function for initialization:

```
RandomGenerator init_rg() {
    RandomGenerator rg;
    rg.Randomize();
    return rg;
}

RandomGenerator myClass::itsGenerator = init_rg();
```

Comment: just be careful when initialising global (static) variables because ordering is not guaranteed.

Answer (score 1):

Just write a function which returns a reference to a properly randomized RandomGenerator and turn itsGenerator into a reference  to a generator:

```
class myClass
{
public:
 // Some methods...

protected:
 // make this a reference to the real generator
 static RandomGenerator& itsGenerator;
public:
 static RandomGenerator& make_a_generator() 
 {
   RandomGenerator *g=0;
    g=new RandomGenerator();
    g->Randomize();
   return *g;
 }
}

RandomGenerator& myClass::itsGenerator=myClass::make_a_generator();
```

Comment: Why so complicated if you can just return a stack-allocated instance and let NRVO take care of the rest or use a function-local `static` instance?

Comment: RandomGenerator needs an accessible copy constructor even with NRVO. I just wanted to avoid unnecessary requirements.

Answer (score 0):

Is it only a one function that needs RandomGenerator? You may do this in this way:

int myClass::foo()
{
    static RandomGenerator itsGenerator = RandomGenerator::Randomize()
    ...
}

Comment: This wouldn't work because Randomize doesn't return a generator. Separating the lines would cause the generator to be randomized each time you enter the block.

Answer (score 0):

If only `myClass` needs the `RandomGenerator`, then:

```
myClass::myClass()
{
    itsGenerator.Randomize();
}
```

Does it matter if you re-randomize your random generator for each object?  I'm assuming no ;-)